# How can I customise the title and body of a tooltip in Apexchart?

Tags: reactjs, charts, jsx, scatter-plot, apexcharts

I am designing a scatter chart from Apexchart to highlight the relationship between two variables. I would like to customize the chart tooltip with a title for each pair of x, y observations.

This is my current set up in JSX (I have assigned the titles to a 'z' variable, but I am not sure it is the correct way):

```
this.state = {
        series: [{
            data: 
            [{
                x: 1,
                y: 2.14,
                z: 'title1'
            }, {
                x: 1.2,
                y: 2.19,
                z: 'title2'
            }, {
                x: 1.8,
                y: 2.43,
                z: 'title3'
            }]
          },
        ],
          options: {
            chart: {
                height: 350,
                type: 'scatter',
              },
              tooltip: {
                z: {
                    formatter: undefined,
                    title: 'Title: '
                }
              }
          }
    };
```

This is the result:

[image]

Instead, I would like to have the different "titles" in the heading/grey section and the two x,y variables in the body of the tooltip.

How can customize the chart options to render the tooltips as intended?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        custom({series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w}) {
          return (
            '<div style="width: 100px; height: 50px;">' +
            "<span>" +
            series[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex] +
            "</span>" +
            "</div>"
          );
        }
      },
```

[so u can make the style as u wish ;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDo8r.png)